# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text' when trying to add a tkinter.Button widget in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter

I have just started to learn how to programme a GUI and am having trouble adding a button widget, when i try to add it, this error message comes up, `"**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text' ". Error occurs when run in both Jupyter Notebook and Spyder (python 3.6) interpreters

```
"""PROJECT"""

from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import math as m

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.title_lbl = Label(self, text = "Please input values down below")
        self.title_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)

        self.shear_x_lbl = Label(self, text = "Sigma-x =")
        self.shear_x_lbl.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.shear_x_ent = Entry(self)
        self.shear_x_ent.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.shear_y_lbl = Label(self, text = "Sigma-y =")
        self.shear_y_lbl.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.shear_y_ent = Entry(self)
        self.shear_y_ent.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)


        self.tau_xy_lbl = Label(self, text = "tau-xy =")
        self.tau_xy_lbl.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.tau_xy_ent = Entry(self)
        self.tau_xy_ent.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.submit_button = Button(self, text="Submit")
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)


root = Tk()
root.title("Longevity")
root.geometry("300x150")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Full error traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-23710b5dc402> in <module>()
     38 root.title("Longevity")
     39 root.geometry("300x150")
---> 40 app = Application(root)
     41 
     42 root.mainloop()

<ipython-input-21-23710b5dc402> in __init__(self, master)
      9         super(Application, self).__init__(master)
     10         self.grid()
---> 11         self.create_widgets()
     12 
     13     def create_widgets(self):

<ipython-input-21-23710b5dc402> in create_widgets(self)
     31         self.tau_xy_ent.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W)
     32 
---> 33         self.submit_button = Button(self, text="Submit")
     34         self.submit_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
     35 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

Comment: What is the _full_ error traceback?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply; running this code on jupyter notebook seems to produce the error

Comment: Also gets the same error when run on Spyder (python 3.6)

Comment: I do not get that error when I run your code in a normal python interpreter. If this is unique to a specific interpreter, you need to mention that in the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is going to be a case of why the **from** *x* **import *** kind of syntax is frowned upon.  When you do that, everything gets tossed into the global namespace.

This can be a problem, for example, when there's both a [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) class in tkinter and a [Button](https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/buttons.html) class in matplotlib.  Admittedly, it's under matplotlib.widgets, but I bet it somehow finds its way into the top level, too, possibly from the interpreter you're using.

Any class that's defined in matplotlib will overwrite a class of the same name from your earlier import.

If my guess is right, the solution is to leave things in their proper 
namespaces.  This is slightly inconvenient, but a good habit - it avoids this exact same name collision that you've encountered.

I think you'll find it working if you use proper namespaces.  I haven't tested this code, but it should get you in the right direction:

```
"""PROJECT"""

import tkinter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m

class Application(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(tkinter.Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.title_lbl = tkinter.Label(self, text = "Please input values down below")
        self.title_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = tkinter.W)

        self.shear_x_lbl = tkinter.Label(self, text = "Sigma-x =")
        self.shear_x_lbl.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.shear_x_ent = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.shear_x_ent.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = tkinter.W)

        self.shear_y_lbl = tkinter.Label(self, text = "Sigma-y =")
        self.shear_y_lbl.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.shear_y_ent = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.shear_y_ent.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = tkinter.W)


        self.tau_xy_lbl = tkinter.Label(self, text = "tau-xy =")
        self.tau_xy_lbl.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.tau_xy_ent = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.tau_xy_ent.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = tkinter.W)

        self.submit_button = tkinter.Button(self, text="Submit")
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.W)


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Longevity")
root.geometry("300x150")
app = tkinter.Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I notice that I didn't add anything from the `plt` namespace.  I haven't looked up every line of your code, but I thought all of those were tkinter calls; do you even use matplotlib.pyplot in this code?  (If you don't, you can get away with importing all of tkinter into the global namespace.  I still think it's dangerous and a bad habit, but it would clean up the code considerably.  As long as it's the only thing you splat-add, you don't have to worry about collisions.)

**EDIT**:
Important note: I'm not an avid user of tkinter, so I was unaware of their conventions, but according to their [docs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html#code):

> Notice that we've imported everything from the tkinter module, so that we can call tkinter functions etc. without prefixing them, which is standard Tkinter practice

So, evidently, it's suggested practice to splat-add everything from tkinter.

With matplotlib, that's not the standard, though - standard practice for pyplot is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Again, as long as you only splat-add one library, you're likely to avoid such namespace collisions.  In your case, changing your line that imported matplotlib is apparently sufficient and satisfy all the standards.

Comment: Yes! Thanks very much. I think I was planning on using matplotlib at some point during my code and never got round to it. I understand that its a bad habit, ill clean it up. Thanks again!